# The difference between ".//*" and "//*" XPath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

The difference between:
1: `".//*"`
and
2: `"//*"`
XPath in the following:
the first one means "from the current context i.e from **this** place/point".
Do I get it right?
What is the sense in such XPath: `".//a[contains(., 'some text')]"`?

Answer (score 2):

While using Selenium you can find elements using `WebDriver` right?

Java example:
`WebElement element = driver.findElement(...)`

But you can also use `element` variable to look for elements in the context of this element. It will not search the whole DOM, it will limit the search to `element`.

Java example:

```
WebElement nestedElement = element.findElement(...);
```

That's where `.//` becomes handy. Because it tells xpath to use current context.

This will search in reduced context:

```
element.findElement(By.xpath(".//div"));
```

This will search through DOM, regardless of using `element`

```
element.findElement(By.xpath("//div"));
```